# Xubuntu 18.04 LTS Install Failure on Acer SP111-32N

Tags: grub2, system-installation, xubuntu, 18.04, acer

I am posting this issue because I had done a great deal of research and work in trying to solve it, resulting currently in a working system with one minor remaining issue.

The basic install method was an initial disposal of the Windows 10 OS by re-partition and format.  Most of the BIOS was tested in a variety of settings, with the final setting being secure boot disabled.

The primary symptom was a 90% install, with the process hanging during the grub2 install.  Later testing determined the grub software was properly installed onto the boot drive, but that it failed in the discovery process determining the OS versions for grub.cfg.  The same hang-up can be replicated in the "working system" if one runs "update-grub."

The "working system" was accomplished by running the install, allowing it to hang and killing the process, then manually creating a grub.cfg file in /boot/grub.

The remaining issue regards system updates, which will hang on any call to update-grub, which means any kernel updates will require the same manual intervention.  I have not determined why it hangs, having spent considerable time and effort to get to this point.

Comment: Usually `update-grub` will list whatever it finds as it finds it. Does it just instantly hang for you? If not, what's the last entry? What's your hard drive/partition layout?

Comment: update-grub found the vmlinuz and initrd and then stopped.  The Memtest files, which were present, are typically found next.  Interestingly, the next ordered element in the ls listing was the efi folder.  Never found the error on the hang to be sure, but that was suspicious.  Partition layout was the default when "Erase entire disk and Install" is selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is an UPDATE, not an answer.  First, the machine operates well with one key exception.  It keeps trying (and failing) at the grub install and configure.  This happens with each software update or new software install. The failure does not time-out, it just hangs...though the computer continues to operate.  I have to kill the job...or just reboot.

I just did a software update to the current version kernel.  It went well, right up to the grub install.  I updated the grub.cfg manually and it works well again.  A bit of a pain, but manageable.